# Copying template of circles and putting them on new position by mouse click

Tags: qgis, cad, copy, circle

I am looking for a way to copy some circles (see at picture) and put them on a new position by a mouse click. Most likely I would like to copy the circle with the different color of lines but the one in one shapefile with just one color would be okay as well.

Building a template of these circles and let me place them where I want them to be, would be great as well. I already tried the copy function with the QAD-Addon but it wont work.

[image]

Comment: The `advanced digitizing toolbar` provides native copying of features. How does this not suit your needs?

Comment: Alright, I didnt see that the feature is getting copied already by ctrl-c. This could already do the job. But is there a way to copy the circle in the top left of my screenshot? The one made by 3 different shapes, because I need to put a symbol in the middle and have different colors of the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select circle, toggle edit mode.
2. Use `Menu Edit / Copy Features` (`Ctrl-C`), then `Menu Edit / Paste Features` (Ctrl-V).
3. To move the pasted circle, click the `Move feature` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#move-feature-s)) icon (activate `Advanced Digitizing toolbar` if not visible: `Menu View / Toolbars`) and move the circle:

[image]

**Edit**

From your comments it becomes clear that you're rather looking after a solution for visualization purpose only. You can do that using [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator) and addig sever [Symbol layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-symbol-layer-tree).

See the screenshot how to add a new symbol layer (green `+`), than select Geometry generator and choose the geometry type you'd like: for a circle, choose `polygon`. Then add the expression that creates the circle, here: `buffer($geometry, 150)` - 150 is the radius, you can change that.

Style the circle (no fill, green outline). You can add as many symbol layers as you want of any (simple fill, Geometry generatoretc.).

*Screenshot showing how the green circle is created. Once set up, the three symbols (red dot, blue and green circle) will be automatically be created whenever you add a point:*
[image]

Comment: Alright, I didnt see that the feature is getting copied already by ctrl-c. This could already do the job. But is there a way to copy the circle in the top left of my screenshot? The one made by 3 different shapes, because I need to put a symbol in the middle and have different colors of the lines.

Comment: Youhave three different layers (red dot in the middle, blue circle (76) and green circle (350). You can only copy features from one layer at a time. What is your goal? If you need it only for visualization (style), you might create these three diffferent circles as symbol layers with Geometry generator. Every time you add a point, these three rings will then be created automatically.

Comment: Well I think this is exactly what I need. Could you maybe explain this a little bit more in detail? When I try to use the geometry generator, its only possible to save one layer?!

Comment: added that to the bottom of my answer

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.